# Are these effects missing from my glm output because of a possible dummy trap?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction, glmm, categorical-encoding

I have a few generalized linear mixed model questions. I have an experiment that  asked "is there a differential response between asexuals and sexuals by population density?". I am performing a generalized linear model with gamma distribution (my data is right-skewed). My model has fixed effects: `Status` (Invasive vs Native), `Density` (low, medium, and high), and `lineage` (CPA, GS, MA, OK, and SY). I am testing an interaction effect among Density treatments and Status. Growth rate is my dependent variable.

```r
Fullmodel <- glmer(Growthrateuntil3mm ~ 
    Status*Density + ((1|Lineage) %in% 
    Status), data=X, family="Gamma")
    boundary (singular) fit: see  
    help('isSingular')
summary(Fullmodel)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Gamma  ( inverse )
Formula: Growthrateuntil3mm ~ Status * Density + ((1 | Lineage) %in% Status)
   Data: X

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -1662.9  -1635.6    839.4  -1678.9      214 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4977 -0.6103 -0.2494  0.3235  4.8206 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Lineage  (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000  
 Residual             0.4458   0.6677  
Number of obs: 222, groups:  Lineage, 5

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 122.650     31.595   3.882 0.000104 ***
StatusNative                -20.969     36.102  -0.581 0.561356    
DensityLow                   -3.538    140.352  -0.025 0.979890    
DensityMedium                12.132     49.567   0.245 0.806639    
StatusNative:DensityLow     -50.180    146.425  -0.343 0.731823    
StatusNative:DensityMedium  -39.987     54.685  -0.731 0.464644    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SttsNt DnstyL DnstyM StN:DL
StatusNativ -0.897                            
DensityLow  -0.615  0.585                     
DensityMedm -0.609  0.551  0.396              
SttsNtv:DnL  0.605 -0.625 -0.988 -0.391       
SttsNtv:DnM  0.561 -0.635 -0.388 -0.919  0.415
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

I understand that **StatusInvasive** was not shown in this output because it is a reference variable, but why is **StatusInvasive:DensityLow** and **StatusInvasive:DensityMedium** not shown here?

I decided to separate data into dummy variables to investigate the interaction effects.

```r
> Model1 <- glmer(Growthrateuntil3mm ~ 
    Status_I:Density_H + Status_N:Density_H 
    + Status_I:Density_M + 
    Status_N:Density_M + Status_I:Density_L 
    + Status_N:Density_L + 
    ((1|Lineage_CPA) %in% Status_I) 
    + ((1|Lineage_GS) %in% Status_N) + 
    ((1|Lineage_SY) %in% Status_I) 
    + ((1|Lineage_MA) %in% Status_N) + 
    ((1|Lineage_OK) %in% Status_N), data=X, 
    family="Gamma")
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 3 columns / coefficients
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
summary(Model1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Gamma  ( inverse )
Formula: Growthrateuntil3mm ~ Status_I:Density_H + Status_N:Density_H +  
    Status_I:Density_M + Status_N:Density_M + Status_I:Density_L +      Status_N:Density_L + ((1 | Lineage_CPA) %in% Status_I) +  
    ((1 | Lineage_GS) %in% Status_N) + ((1 | Lineage_SY) %in%  
    Status_I) + ((1 | Lineage_MA) %in% Status_N) + ((1 | Lineage_OK) %in%      Status_N)
   Data: X

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -1654.9  -1614.0    839.4  -1678.9      210 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4977 -0.6103 -0.2494  0.3235  4.8206 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Lineage_CPA (Intercept) 1.783e-14 1.335e-07
 Lineage_GS  (Intercept) 2.294e-14 1.515e-07
 Lineage_SY  (Intercept) 1.654e-47 4.067e-24
 Lineage_MA  (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
 Lineage_OK  (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
 Residual                4.458e-01 6.677e-01
Number of obs: 222, groups:  Lineage_CPA, 2; Lineage_GS, 2; Lineage_SY, 2; Lineage_MA, 2; Lineage_OK, 2

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          47.963      7.548   6.354 2.09e-10 ***
Status_I             71.149     29.113   2.444   0.0145 *  
Status_I:Density_H    3.538     31.025   0.114   0.9092    
Density_H:Status_N   53.718     10.639   5.049 4.44e-07 ***
Status_I:Density_M   15.670     33.586   0.467   0.6408    
Status_N:Density_M   25.863     10.228   2.529   0.0115 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Stts_I S_I:D_H D_H:S_ S_I:D_M
Status_I    -0.259                              
Stts_I:Dn_H  0.000 -0.875                       
Dnsty_H:S_N -0.709  0.184  0.000                
Stts_I:Dn_M  0.000 -0.809  0.759   0.000        
Stts_N:Dn_M -0.738  0.191  0.000   0.524  0.000 
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 3 columns / coefficients
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

The random effect is still near singularity so I decided to run Lineage as a fixed effect. I have removed the nested effect of Status from other model attempts and there was still singularity.

```r
model2 <- glm(Growthrateuntil3mm ~ 
    Status_I:Density_H + Status_N:Density_H
    + Status_I:Density_M + 
    Status_N:Density_M + 
    Status_I:Density_L +
    Status_N:Density_L + Lineage_CPA + 
    Lineage_GS + Lineage_MA + Lineage_OK + 
    Lineage_SY + Status_I +Status_N + 
    Density_H + Density_L + Density_M, 
    data=X, family="Gamma")
summary(model2)

Call:
glm(formula = Growthrateuntil3mm ~ Status_I:Density_H + Status_N:Density_H + 
    Status_I:Density_M + Status_N:Density_M + Status_I:Density_L + 
    Status_N:Density_L + Lineage_CPA + Lineage_GS + Lineage_MA + 
    Lineage_OK + Lineage_SY + Status_I + Status_N + Density_H + 
    Density_L + Density_M, family = "Gamma", data = X)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-7.6854  -0.4318  -0.1351   0.2159   2.1249  

Coefficients: (8 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         157.626     30.819   5.115    7e-07 ***
Lineage_CPA         -35.255     19.602  -1.799 0.073499 .  
Lineage_GS          -73.048     31.081  -2.350 0.019675 *  
Lineage_MA          -69.825     31.198  -2.238 0.026250 *  
Lineage_OK         -102.676     30.199  -3.400 0.000804 ***
Lineage_SY               NA         NA      NA       NA    
Status_I                 NA         NA      NA       NA    
Status_N                 NA         NA      NA       NA    
Density_H            28.532      9.860   2.894 0.004203 ** 
Density_L           -22.713      9.745  -2.331 0.020700 *  
Density_M                NA         NA      NA       NA    
Status_I:Density_H  -50.285     31.926  -1.575 0.116731    
Density_H:Status_N       NA         NA      NA       NA    
Status_I:Density_M  -10.460     34.213  -0.306 0.760114    
Status_N:Density_M       NA         NA      NA       NA    
Status_I:Density_L       NA         NA      NA       NA    
Status_N:Density_L       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.432259)

    Null deviance: 613.13  on 221  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 586.09  on 213  degrees of freedom
AIC: -1664.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

I assume this last model is rank deficient because of the dummy trap, but I included all dummy variables in this model - how do I fix this issue? Also, should I keep Lineage as a random effect and run bayesglmer to fix singularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only 5 values of `Lineage` you are getting yourself into trouble trying to treat it as a random effect. That typically leads to singularity problems with the random effect, as you observed. Furthermore, your attempts to code the interaction terms by hand seem to be causing problems.

Don't overthink this. If you think that `Lineage` has a simple additive effect on outcome, as is implicit in your modeling with random intLercepts, just let the software do the work for you.

```
glm(formula = Growthrateuntil3mm ~ Status*Density + Lineage, family = "Gamma", data = X)
```

The problem with your manual coding is related to your question about your first model:

> I understand that `StatusInvasive` was not shown in this output because it is a reference variable, but why is `StatusInvasive:DensityLow` and `StatusInvasive:DensityMedium` not shown here?

With the usual treatment coding, the reference level of a categorical predictor is omitted not only from the intercept *but also from all interaction terms* involving it. Putting aside `Lineage` for now, there are only 6 combinations of `Status` and `Density`. All you can estimate is 6 coefficients corresponding to their combinations: such as the 6 coefficients shown as fixed effects in the first model. Even if you ask for more than 6, you can only get 6 linearly independent coefficients. The software will either fail to fit or will internally choose 6 to present.

I can't readily work through what you did in your last model. With your manual coding you asked for more coefficients than are linearly independent, so the software only provided coefficients for a linearly independent subset of what you requested. Specify the model I suggest and the software will minimize the chance of your making an error.